# Add X-Frame-Options header to all URLs using CloudFront functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a single page application and I'm trying to prevent clickjacking by adding X-Frame-Options header to the HTML responses. My website is hosted on S3 through CloudFront.

The CloudFront distribution is configured to send `index.html` by default:

```
Default root object
index.html
```

In the Error Pages section I configured 404 page to also point to the `index.html`. This way all URLs that are not in S3 return the default HTML, i.e. `/login`, `/admin` etc.

[image: 404 error page config]

**Update** The 403 status code is also configured:
[image: 403 error page config]

Then I have created a CloudFront function as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-security-headers.html) and assigned it to the Viewer response:

```
function handler(event) {
    var response = event.response;
    var headers = response.headers;

    headers['x-frame-options'] = {value: 'DENY'}; 

    return response;
}
```

This works, but only for `/`:

```
curl -v https://<MYSITE.com>
....
< x-frame-options: DENY
```

For other URLs it doesn't work - the x-frame-options header is missing:

```
curl -v https://<MYSITE.com>/login
....
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

My question is - why my cloudfront function does not append a header in the error response, and what can I do to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that your questions are:

- Q1: Why does the CloudFront function work for `/`?
- Q2: Why doesn't the CloudFront function work for other url path?

Please refer to the responses below:

- A1: Since you might specify a `Default Root Object` [[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html#DefaultRootObjectHowToDefine) (e.g.`index.html`) which returning the object when a user requests the root URL. When CloudFront returns the object with `200 ok`, the CloudFront Function will be invoked on the `viewer response` event.
- A2: You might not give the `s3:ListBucket` permissions in your S3 bucket policy(e.g. [OAI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)). As the result, you will get  `Access Denied`(403) errors for missing objects instead of 404 Not Found errors. Namely, the `Error Pages` you have configured isn't applied to this case, and the CloudFront Function won't be invoked because the HTTP status code is higher than 399[[2]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html#function-restrictions-status-codes).

`[Updated]` Suggestion:

- Since CloudFront does not invoke edge functions for `viewer response` events when the origin returns HTTP status code 400 or higher. However, Lambda@Edge functions for `origin response` events are invoked for all origin responses. In this senario, I'll suggest that we should use Lambda@Edge instead of CloudFront Functions.
- For your convenience, please refer to the sample code of l@e:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;
   
    headers['x-frame-options'] = [{
        key: 'X-Frame-Options',
        value: 'DENY',
    }];

    return response;
};
```

- FYI. Here is my curl test result:

```
# PATH: `/`
$ curl -sSL -D - https://dxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "e59ff97941044f85df5297e1c302d260"
___snipped___
Server: AmazonS3
X-Frame-Options: DENY
___snipped___

# PATH: `/login`
$ curl -sSL -D - https://dxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/login
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "e59ff97941044f85df5297e1c302d260"
___snipped___
Server: AmazonS3
X-Frame-Options: DENY
___snipped___
```

Comment: 403 is also configured. I updated my answer with the screenshot.

Comment: Hi @ischenkodv,

Thank you for the information. After I did some tests at my end, I can confirm that CloudFront Functions won't be invoked when the origin returns HTTP status code higher than 399. (It doesn't work even if we use custom error response and  modify the HTTP code).

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'd like to suggest you can look into Lambda@Edge and use it to add the security headers. My apology that I didn't test it out before I wrote my first suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for you help. Your solution looks good but somehow this still doesn't work in my environment. I created a Lambda@Edge function, selected it for the Origin Response, but header is not added to the output (maybe I need to invalidate cache?). I'll keep investigating. Meanwhile I use the following workaround. I have 2 cloudfront functions: a viewer request function parses the URL and redirects some requests to `index.html`, and then viewer response function adds headers. This way it always works, but a drawback is that there are 2 functions plus the need to parse requests.

Comment: I created new invalidation to clear the cache and now it works. Thank you!